# Nginx rewrite params/args to directories

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am looking at redirecting urls with paramaters into directories with files that are named with the param with the nginx redirect module.

eg redirect http://mydomain.com/beep?page=3

to

http://mydomain.com/redirect/pages/3.json

I have tried several times but have failed miserably...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might work, depending on your nginx version.

```
location /beep {
    return 301 http://example.com/redirect/page/$arg_page.json
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (as that would send it out back to our load balancer - should have mentioned that in the question) but $arg_page was exactly what I was looking for and helped me solve this, in the end I used: rewrite ^(/beep?) /redirect/pages/$arg_page.json    thank you!

Comment: I got confused because you said the word 'redirect' in your question, didn't notice you said 'rewrite' in the question title, your rewrite works, but it's not entirely correct, you wrote `(/beep?)` I think the `?` isn't actually matching the one in the URL, instead it's saying that the letter `p` is optional, try the URL `example.com/bee?page=3` and I think it would work, I'll fix my answer to do a rewrite instead of a redirect soon.